# Estoy intentando hacer una excepcion(que si sale un numero negativo, me imprima un mensaje)

Tags: java

Clase excepciones, aqui intenté con este codigo, pero lo que imprime es NaN, psdt: ya intente pasarle un if si es NaN, pero aún así no lo coge :/..............

```
    public class Excepciones{

  private double x;
private double resultado;

 public Excepciones() {
}
 
 
 public Excepciones(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void leerNumero1() throws IOException, ArithmeticException{
      resultado =  (7 - Math.log(x));
}


 /*
public void leerNumero2() throws Exception{
    resultado = (7 - Math.log(x));
    if (Double.isNaN(resultado)) {
        throw new Exception("El resultado es NaN");
    }else if(resultado <0)
    {
        throw new Exception("El resultado es negativo");
    }
    System.out.println(resultado);
    
}*/

    public void leerNumero() throws IOException, ArithmeticException{
         try{
             leerNumero1();
             
   } catch(ArithmeticException e){
                 System.out.print("Numero negativo " + e.getMessage()); 
   }catch(IOException ex){
       if(resultado <0){
        System.out.print("Es negativo " +  ex.getMessage());   
       }
   }
    System.out.print("El resultado es: "+ resultado);
    }
```

}

Metodo main: -------------------------------------------

```
package Excepcion;




public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Excepciones ex = new Excepciones(-4);
    
    ex.leerNumero();
```

Se los agradeceria bastante comunidad, muchas gracias :) psdt, le borre codigo al main, porque no me deja subir la pregunta.

Comment: El método java.lang.Math.log() devuelve el logaritmo natural (base e) de un valor,Si el argumento es **NaN** o menor que cero , entonces el resultado es **NaN**, vos estas pasando -4 por eso el resultado

Comment: Lo sé, es que con la formula planteada, solo me da numeros positivos, o bueno siempre es 1.tanto, por eso probaba con los numeros negativos en si

Comment: si esperas obtener un valor negativo,solo seria si le pasara como parametro 0 y te regresaria **-infinity** resultado=Math.log(0);

Comment: Exacto, también probé asi, pues imagina que sea una suma como por ejemplo: 5 - 9, el resultado es -4, ahí si cogería la excepción? en el catch?

Comment: el try catch se usa para excepciones que te hace pensar que un resultado negativo o Nan es una excepción??? si queres lanzar el mensaje de es un negativo solo tendrias que poner la condicional fuera del catch o sea después de usar el método leernumero1

Comment: Eso lo hice desde un principio, pero me piden pasar por try y catch, y pensaba que estaba mal planteado o que mi cabeza no da para esa logica jaja

Comment: pues el uso de Math.log() no arroja ninguna excepción, quizá te pidieron el uso de try catch por si ingresases un dato erróneo u otra eventualidad

Comment: lo que te aconsejo es que crees tu propia [exepcion](https://parzibyte.me/blog/2021/04/14/excepcion-personalizada-java/#:~:text=cuanto%20al%20error.-,Creando%20excepci%C3%B3n%20propia%20en%20Java,pas%C3%A1ndole%20el%20mensaje%20de%20error.) para cuando obtenegas un valor negativo pero usando mathlog solo obtendras el -infinity ;)

Comment: Pues no, dice: si resultado es negativo, capturar el error ...

Comment: `if(resultado <0){
            throw new Exception ("Es negativo " );   
           }
        }`

Comment: Pues me brincó la excepcion pero runtime xd jajaj

Comment: Osea, que si esta bien que me brinque runtime bro(?